# How to calculate the partial derivative of the loss function?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, gradient-descent

I have the following loss function:

\begin{equation}
    J_{\mathcal D}(\vec \theta)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(\text{loss}_{({\vec x}^{(i)}, y^{(i)})}(\Theta)\right)
\end{equation}

With this as cross entropy:
\begin{equation}
    \text{loss}_{({\vec x}^{(i)}, y^{(i)})}(\vec \theta) = -y^{(i)} \cdot log(h_{\Theta} ({\vec x}^{(i)})) - (1-y^{(i)}) \cdot log(1-h_\Theta({\vec x}^{(i)}))
\end{equation}

The hypothesis: $$
h_\Theta(\vec x) = \sigma(\vec x'^T \cdot \vec \theta)
$$
with the logistic function:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

What is the partial derivative of the cross entropy?

Comment: got it = $$
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(h_\Theta({\vec x}^{(i)}) - y^{(i)}\right)x^{(i)}_j
\end{equation}$$

Comment: Note that the gradient will be null when the prediction/hypothesis will match the target. This makes sense.